# saltstack cmd.run variable expansion

Tags: powershell, saltstack

I can get salt to let me run keytool this way:

```
salt [host] cmd.run shell=powershell '& "$JRE_HOME/bin/keytool.exe" --help'
```

But I can't figure out how to put this into a state file. A straightforward translation fails saying "& was unexpected at this time".

```
cmd.run:
 - shell: powershell
 - name: '& "$JRE_HOME/bin/keytool.exe" --help'
```

I've tried dozens of variations on this, but have yet to find one that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled upon a solution.

```
  - name: ; & "${env:JRE_HOME}/bin/keytool" --help
```